# Compare data in specific columns in 2 tables with an output of discrepancies

Tags: sql-server-2012

So I have 2 tables hours(T1) and codes(T2) I need to identify any row in T1 where T1.columnA = T2.columnB and T1.columnC not equal to T2.ColumnD

I got this far to identify the first part but blank on where how to compare CloumnB&C to only when the below is true.

```
SELECT *
FROM Hours 
where columnA in (select columnB FROM Codes)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackoverFlow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [read about how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
SELECT * FROM hours T1
INNER JOIN codes T2 ON T1.columnA = T2.columnB
WHERE T1.columnC != T2.ColumnD;
```

Comment: Looks good however columnC & ColumnD are both nvarchar fields

Comment: I think I had a moment all I needed to do was add ' '

Comment: Was it useful to you? 
I prepared this one based on you explanation in question. SO guideline say that you need to ask proper question with proper example and code.